# Elasticsearch - different results with different clients

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch with a PHP client.  However, when I construct a simple query, it gives drastically different results against the same index than what I believe is the equivalent query via Curl or Python.  I.e., the results are entirely unrelated to the query - seems like a random chunk of data.  It also returns these same results regardless of the value of the parameter (last name) I send.  Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'directory',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'last_name' => 'ely'
                ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = @$client->search($params);
print_r($response);
?>
```

And here is the Curl equivalent, that returns accurate results:

```
http://localhost:9200/directory/_search?q=last_name:ely
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you remove the @ in front of $client->search ? You probably have some errors that are masked.

Comment: My apologies, I left out the error piece.  The client->search call does give this error: `Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/es/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Serializers/SmartSerializer.php on line 30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting comes from [this line](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/2ab397170d8732d3b24bb5c2482e209fd6df5759/src/Elasticsearch/Serializers/SmartSerializer.php#L30) in `SmartSerializer.php`

```
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

You can see that the second argument `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` has been added in [this commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/commit/2ab3971), which also [requires PHP version 5.6.6](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/pull/481)

So the problem comes from the fact that you're using the latest version of elasticsearch-php which needs PHP 5.6.6, but your PHP version is lower than that, and hence, `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` does not exist in your PHP version.

Comment: Thanks very much - I upgraded to 7.1 and the problem indeed went away!

Comment: Would be happy to but I don't see that option... will poke around a bit.